# Basic android studio project with errors

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I just downloaded the Android 3.1 and I created a new project with a Basic Activity, but it doesn't recognize the Theme and other things, never happen before and sometimes some new activities comes with no ActionBar, its like transparent.

[image]

And

Any thoughts ? Thanks!

[image]

Gradle App level

[image]

Gradle project Level the same version of the Android Studio

[image]

Comment: StackOverflow encourages you to use the code formatting instead of images, please check [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) for some details on it.

Comment: Sure, but in this case, it was better to show the image with the error cuz its unusual!

Comment: He can not post some code, because code does not show red color

Answer (score 0):

I face this error often, that is actually an issue in AS. Your project will still run, and successful build.

This is just a editor error.

To resolve this

- update your version of `com.android.support` libraries in app level build.gradle.
- And gradle plugin version as same as your Android studio version in your project level build.gradle.
- Update compileSdkVersion and buildToolVersion (or you can remove in with latest gradle version) to latest.

like i have 3.1.2 version of Android studio so i have

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        ...
    }
}
```

Clean, Rebuild and Enjoy.

Comment: I think I already have all these things as default, I'll update my question.